# Add a note/message to Google Charts at specific places

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts to display some data related to the performance of a web page (bounce rate, volume, etc). When I make changes to the page (for example changing the color of a button), I keep track of that using small notes (for example: 'week 15 2014: button is now green').

I'd like to display these notes (with a hover-over function to display the text) IN the chart. So vertically they should be at the right location (right week). Horizontally it doesn't matter where they're placed, on top  or bottom would be most logical. What would be the best approach to succeed in doing so?

JSFiddle of my current chart: http://jsfiddle.net/9qukjbhg/

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Interval', 'Bounce Rate', 'Call to Action Succeed', 'Total Volume'],
        ['week 36', 0.3283, 0.4328, 67],
        ['week 37', 0.2857, 0.4167, 84],
        ['week 38', 0.1562, 0.5417, 96],
        ['week 39', 0.275, 0.4125, 80],
        ['week 40', 0.2615, 0.4154, 65],
        ['week 41', 0.2213, 0.3588, 131],
        ['week 42', 0.2232, 0.5, 112],
        ['week 43', 0.3476, 0.3898, 118],
        ['week 44', 0.3025, 0.4118, 119],
        ['week 45', 0.294, 0.3897, 136],
        ['week 46', 0.2043, 0.4286, 49]
    ]);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: '#,###%'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    formatter.format(data, 2);

    var options = {


        vAxes: {
            0: {
                format: '#,###%'
            },
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }
        },

        1: {
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }

        },
        series: {
            0: {
                targetAxisIndex: 0,
                type: 'bars'
            },
            1: {
                targetAxisIndex: 0,
                type: 'bars'
            },
            2: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            }
        },

        title: 'Page performance per week'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

What I try to do (something like this, see the note on the right top of the image): [image: Chart with note]

Who can point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to add your own div with the necessary text and picture and with `position: absolute. Then calculate its coordinates somehow so that it is over your chart.